# How to catch bugs on clients' devices?

Tags: android, debugging, remote-debugging

I've seen too many bugs on clients devices which I cannot reproduce on my own devices. So far, the only solution was to publish hidden app and let them report all app crashes.

Is there a better way?

Namely, the app is crashing on clients tablet, while it does not on my. How can I catch this crash?

Comment: try this service: https://bugsnag.com/

Comment: I assume you know of ACRA http://acra.ch/ and the crash logs on the Developer Console. Is there something more specific you are looking for?

Comment: @MorrisonChang Anything without publishing the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using ACRA library
https://github.com/ACRA/acra
but you need to publish a new version in this case.

Comment: Anything without publishing?

Comment: @sandalone how do you know that your app is crashing on other devices?
where did you get these data?

Comment: The clients told me then recorded a video of it. I do the same steps and the app is not crashing.

Comment: @sandalone, there is no way to get crash report/log without wraping your application using ACRA or using google analytics, and that needs to push a new version of your application

Answer (score 0):

Although ACRA is a solution accepted by most of Android developers, I also tried TestFlight service. I have been using it for ages to test iOS apps and as of recently they have been supporting Android as well.

Testing is very simple. You import their JAR and create a custom `Application` class. There is a simple and precise tutorial on their website.

I can upload the APK to their service and myself and all my testers can test it. The service can detect crashes, but you can also send it your custom messages via `TestFlight.log()` method.